# Best way to use of setters in OOP

Tags: oop, coding-style, setter

Let's assume I have a class and whenever I set certain attributes `bla`, `foo` (which can be set externally and internally) I want to call another method of the class, let's call it `onChangeFunction()`.

Would it be a good way to simply call `onChangeFunction()` when setting internal values directly, e.g.

```
function someFunction()
  // Some Calculations here ...
  this.bla = some_value;
  this.onChangeFunction()
end
```

or would it be better to also set those variables `bla` and `foo` ONLY by using the internal setter-methods because there is a certain action triggered with it and thus it would be a more clearly arranged code.

I even go a step further: Let's say I don't need an extern setter which can be called from outside (access type = `public`), would it than still be good to invent a `private` setter to do the same approach and only use the setter because of the triggered set-action?
**EDIT**: What I mean is the following: Even if I would NOT have a public setter (because there should not be a public access to set the variable, because it's only an internal variable) would it be still good to have a setter which is `private`-only just because of the triggered action thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the long term it is much less error-prone to always use a setter, and to call `onChangeFunction()` from within the setter.

You don't specify which programming languages you have in mind, but some languages allow one to define a "property" that looks like a data member but always calls a function when an attempt is made to change it. See, for example, [`property` et al](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) in Python.

As to your second question, I don't think there's anything wrong with having a `private` setter.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yeah I think also that it's less error prone, I was just wondering if it's not a bit overcomplicating things by using setters from internal routines instead of directly accessing the values. The language I'm currently thinking of is MATLAB but it's rather a general question. But thanks for your tip, didn't know that something like this exists. To my second question: Okay, I was just wondering if this is common practise because up to now, I thought `getters-setters` are rather a concept to make some private vars accessible to the 'outside'.

Comment: @ColHeather: We're discussing having a two-line setter, and replacing two lines of code at every call site with one. To be honest, I wouldn't call this "overcomplicating".

Comment: @ColHeather: I've already updated the answer to address the edit. However, knowing SO it might take a few minutes before you see the changes I made. In a nutshell: in my view, there's nothing wrong with having a `private` setter.

Comment: Haha yes, thanks, you're just faster than me. I've edited mine also to address your edit, but you probably still read the old post since I wasn't fast enough :) EDIT: Oh cool, MATLAB also offers the functionality of `property access methods`, see here if somebody is interested in it: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brgsek9-1.html